# Frame size in init differs after touch

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a feeling the answer will be pretty obvious but I just can't find the answer to my question. So sorry if i'm asking something that has been asked before.

When tracing the **frame height** of an **uiview** in the **init** it states that the height is **480px**. 
When i trace the same height **after a gesture** (or out of the `if (self)`) has been done it states that the height is **460px**, so it 'removes' the status bar from the frame. I don't really understand why this happens, it makes dynamic vertical centering a pain in the ass. I would want the frame to be 460px in the init so i don't have to subtract 10px to get my views/images centered.

I just made a simple project with nothing in it, i've set it up like this:

### Controller

```c
- (void)loadView
{
    CGRect frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    self.centerview = [[CenterView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [self setView:self.centerview];
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: And what will you do with iphone5 screen size? (if you have your view coordinates hardcoded)

Comment: @Vladimir : That's the problem, and that's why i'm asking this question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `applicationFrame` instead of `bounds` on the `mainScreen`. From the docs:

> This property contains the screen bounds minus the area occupied by
>   the status bar, if it is visible. Using this property is the
>   recommended way to retrieve your application’s initial window size.
>   The rectangle is specified in points.

The 2nd problem about adding a new view to centerview is probably because of mixing bounds and frame. If you want a new view to be added the same size as centerview and in the same position, do this:

```
UIView *newView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.centerView.bounds];
[self.centerView addSubview:newView];
```

Comment: It works, in the way that the *centerview* still fills the whole visible area, but when i declare a new view in the *centerview* i have a blank space at the top, under the status bar, that's the same height as the status bar. So how does that work?

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to add that i have this problem only when making a view initwithframe:self.frame. But when i make a new cgrect starting from 0,0 it works fine. This is solving my problem so far, so thank you for this answer! Do you also know how this comes that the frame is 48Opx at first but 460 later on?

Comment: the bounds of the screen is always 480, its just that your view gets resized to 460 because it doesnt include the status bar. The offset you have is probably coming from mixing up frame and bounds: bounds will always have 0,0 as origin, frame will be have an origin relative to its superview

Comment: Ok i see. It's just weird because this was the only way we saw it in school. Your solution worked so thanks alot for your help :)

Comment: 10 months later -- So sorry man, I totally forgot to upvote your answer!

Answer (score 0):

The size of the UIScreen includes the status bar and any other elements such as the Nav bar and the Tab bar so on an iPhone 4S or lower will be 480. The size of the UIView will only be the usable space.

If you do not need the status bar you could hide it so then you have the full size of the screen to play with.

Better still get the size of the view you are loading so you could do

```
CGRect frame = self.view.superview.bounds;
```

Instead of using the UIScreen

Comment: calling self.view.bounds in loadView would be an infinite loop, you'd need to call super first

Comment: @AdamRichardson: I see you updated the code, but this still results in the same behavior as your previous answer? It does not show anything but a black screen